# c# Can logged in credentials (non explicit) be used with wsmanconnectioninfo?

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I have the function below with multiple threads, which was fine with explicit credentials when I was the only one using it, but I've been asked to put it into a powershell script where it will be plain text to leverage the multithread capability.

Is it possible to use the implied credentials of the account running the script with wsmanconnectioninfo? If not, is there a different way to create the Exchange shell connection without explicit credentials?

```
    private Collection<PSObject> runPowerShellScript(object server)
    {
        Collection<PSObject> psobjs = new Collection<PSObject>();
        string result = "";
        string serverName = server.ToString();

        string loginPassword = "xxx";
        System.Security.SecureString secpassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in loginPassword)
        {
            secpassword.AppendChar(c);
        }

        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(@"domain/samaccount", secpassword);
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://xxxxx/powershell"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential);
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;

        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
        {
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();

            if (runspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State == RunspaceState.Opened)
            {
                // do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                runspace.Open();
                powershell.Runspace = runspace;
            }

            try
            {
                PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
                command.AddScript($@"get-mailboxdatabase -Server " + server + " -Status");
                powershell.Commands = command;                    
                psobjs = powershell.Invoke();

                if (powershell.HadErrors == true)
                {
                    result = "Failed - " + powershell.Streams.Error[0].ToString();
                    result = result.Replace("\"", "*");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string fail = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        object serverNameO = server;
        PSObject serverNameObj = new PSObject(serverNameO);
        psobjs.Insert(0, serverNameObj);

        return psobjs;
    }
```

Comment: You can translate that directly to PowerShell without changing much at all.  Check out the [PoshRSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) module.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use 3rd party modules ... is there another way to connect to ExchangeShell with c# that doesn't require explicit credentials?

Comment: I tried this today and it is working so far

WSManConnectionInfo wmc = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://xxx/powershell"));
            wmc.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
            wmc.ShellUri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange";

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
WSManConnectionInfo wmc = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(`"http://xxx/powershell`"));
wmc.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
wmc.ShellUri = `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange`";

using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(wmc))
{

}
```